# Session not being created even though Set-Cookie header is being sent

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have three services, namely be, fe and auth. All the three services are hosted on App Engine and I have load balancer in place to have them all on the same domain. On user login, I want a session to be created. Even though on login, the set-cookie header is sent, I can see that in the developer tools. In the cookie or session storage section, nothing is getting saved. Hence each of my subsequent request is faling as I have an auth in place which checks if req.session = true.

Here is my session file:

```
const session = require("express-session");
const connectRedis = require("connect-redis");
const redisClient = require("./../services/redisConnection").redis_client;
const CONFIG = require("../config/index");

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);

module.exports = session({
  store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
  secret: CONFIG.SESSION_SECRET,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  name: "id", // random
  cookie: {
    path: "/",
    secure: CONFIG.NODE_ENV === "local" ? false : true, // if true: only transmit cookie over https, in prod, always activate this
    httpOnly: CONFIG.NODE_ENV === "local" ? false : true, // if true: prevents client side JS from reading the cookie
    maxAge: parseInt(CONFIG.SESSION_MAXAGE), // session max age in milliseconds
    sameSite: "none",
    // TODO: change this to the main domain when configuration is complete
    domain: "apply-itpwexp.com",
  },
});
```

Login Function:

```
//TODO: Add a check if the disabled field is true
// If it's true login would not be allowed

async function login(req, res) {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if (!email || !password) {
    res.status(401).send({
      message:
        "Bad request params - you need to provide an email and a password",
    });
    return;
  }
  try {
    const validated = await authenticate(email, password);
    req.session.user = validated;
    console.log(req.session);
    res.status(200).send({
      message: "Successfully logged in!",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error("Error in authenticating: " + error);
    res.status(401).send({
      message: "Error: " + error,
    });
    return;
  }
}
```

Authentication function from login

```
async function authenticate(email, password) {
  try {
    const user = await Admin.findOne({ email: email });
    if (user === null) {
      logger.error("Email is not valid!");
      return Promise.reject("Email is not valid!");
    }
    const match = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    if (match) {
      const user_info = {
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        adminId: user._id,
      };
      return user_info;
    } else {
      logger.error("Password is not valid!");
      return Promise.reject("Password is not valid!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error("Something went wrong: " + err);
    return Promise.reject("Something went wrong");
  }
}
```

And my auth middleware:

```
function authenticate(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session) {
    res.status(401).send({
      message: "You shall not pass",
    });
    return;
  }

  req.adminId = req.session.user.adminId;
  next();
}

module.exports = authenticate;
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. There was an issue in the FE code. The fetch call needs to have a param, `credentials: include`.